# Bundling Windows Applications

Tags: windows, software-bundling

I am looking for a way to bundle a collection of support files for my windows application created with PyInstaller. The PyInstaller OneFile is too slow to instantiate, but I am worried about the integrity and dissemination of the application in a directory structure. Are there any workarounds for bundling the files that still allow me to run the executable without completely unpackaging everything?

Comment: Take a look at some of the answers here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/9469932/7411885. "One file" mode unpacks to a (temporary) directory structure too, so I'm not sure what your worries are there. If the unpack is taking too long on app startup, then "one directory" mode is the way to go. Huge imports and such will always be slow anyways, so after certain point it's more about the complexity/size of the app itself

Comment: @Cpt.Whale OneDirectory mode is 10x faster to load than OneFile (10s vs 100s) - so I am trying to package up this Directory so that the files aren't necessarily "loose" on the filesystem. My imports are all necessary and unfortunately are quite large.

Comment: That's what PyInstaller does - it copies all the compiled files into one folder for you. Just zip it and distribute? https://pyinstaller.org/en/latest/operating-mode.html#bundling-to-one-folder If you want to be a bit cleaner, you could wrap that with PyQt or in a self-extracting zip, but the end result is the same with a single exe in a folder with its dependencies

Comment: @Cpt.Whale zipping works good for distribution but how can I "keep it zipped" and still execute the contained exe? Basically, I'd like to make it slightly more difficult for users to access all the supporting files.

Comment: Maybe look into Nuitka instead to compile everything into C binaries? It also has a single-file mode, but would probably have similar extraction times.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Interesting! How have I never heard of this - I'll give it a shot!